# Как получить дату последних измененных (новых) файлов в директории?

Tags: bash, tar

хочу скриптом ежедневно таром архивировать только новые файлы из директории (в эту папку ежедневно бэкапятся новые или измененные файлы с удаленного сервера).

как мне в скрипте получить дату последних измененных (новых) файлов в директории?

Comment: через `find -mtime`

Comment: + при каждом вызове скрипта сохранять время вызова в какую-то папочку а потом искать все что больше

Answer (score 1):

я бы предложил ориентироваться на какой-нибудь «флаговый» файл, который будет обновляться каждый раз после проведения архивации: всё, что будет новее этого файла, надо будет в следующий раз заархивировать.

один раз создайте такой файл (с произвольным именем):

```
$ touch flag.file
```

а потом программой `find` находите всё, что новее этого файла (опция `-mindepth 1` нужна для того, чтобы в выдачу не попадала ссылка сам каталог, в котором вы выполняете эту команду):

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -newer flag.file
```

вывод этой команды можно (например, с помощью `xargs`) передать как список файлов программе `tar`:

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -newer flag.file | xargs tar -czf /путь/к/создаваемому/архиву
```

не забывайте после создания архива обновить «флаговый» файл:

```
$ touch flag.file
```